# Prime on the product symbol

Tags: superscripts

I want to have a primed product symbol, i.e. something like

```
$\prod^\prime$
```

but it puts the prime on top of the product symbol instead of next to it (as a superscript, as it usually works). Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Just curious, is it a conventional notation, or your own thing? And what does it stand for?

Comment: The notation is introduced by my teacher in a homework assignment to denote a product which only runs till a certainly value. Of course, one should just use the natural limits that come with \prod, but I guess everyone has its own way.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `amsmath` package has a `\sideset` command for this purpose:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \sideset{}{'}\prod_{n=-k}^k \frac{a_n}{n}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

The general syntax is

```
\sideset{_a^b}{_c^d}\sum
```

producing

[image: Full sample]

and works on any large operator `\prod`, `\sum`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You have to detach the superscript from the operator. Below I've inserted a `\vphantom` that is the size of `\prod`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \prod_{i=0}^n f_i \quad \prod{\vphantom\prod}'
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why not ${\prod}'$?  (Actually it seems that even $\prod^\prime$ no longer produces the behaviour described in the post, so maybe you were dealing with some necessity that 4 years has removed.)